# Twitter API returns "Could not authenticate you" error if parameters are present in URL

Tags: php, json, api, url, twitter

I'm trying to load a [Twitter users friend](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list) list through OAuth 1.0a.
It works if the URL doesn't have any parameters, e.g.:

Works: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json`

Doesn't work: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=-1&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false`

If I add parameters to it, I get this error returned:

> Could not authenticate you

What could be the reason for that?
My code:

```
<?php
$oauthToken = 'removed'; 
$oauthTokenSecret = 'removed'; 

function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params)
{
    $r = array(); 
    ksort($params); 
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value); 
    }            

    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth)
{
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\""; 

    $r .= implode(', ', $values); 
    return $r; 
}

//WORKS:
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json';

//DOESN'T WORK, WHY?:
//$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=-1&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false';

$consumer_key = 'removed';
$consumer_secret = 'removed';

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                'oauth_nonce' => time(),
                'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                'oauth_token' => $oauthToken,
                'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                'oauth_version' => '1.0');

$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);

$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauthTokenSecret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;


$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);

echo "JSON: ".$json;

curl_close($feed);
?>
```

Comment: Can this be helpful to you maybe: http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/taming-the-twitter-api-v1-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include your parameters in your OAuth headers. The best way to do this is to break them out from the URL.

```
$params = array(
    "cursor" => -1,
    "skip_status" => "true",
    "include_user_entities" => "false"
);
```

Now build the base string using the base url.

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json'
$oAuthHeaders = $oauth + $params;
$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oAuthHeaders);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauthTokenSecret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oAuthHeaders['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;
```

Finally, create the URLString with additional parameters:

```
if ($params) {
   $finalURL = "$url?";
   foreach ($params as $key=>$param) {
       $finalURL .= rawurlencode($key) . "=" . rawurlencode($param) . "&";
   }
   $finalURL = substr($finalURL, 0, strlen($finalURL) - 1);
}
```

Now you're ready to send the whole package off:

```
$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oAuthHeaders), 'Expect:');
```

Answer (score 0):

The url have params too, so you should try to follow this (in your function buildBaseString):

1. Convert the HTTP Method to uppercase and set the output string equal to this value.
2. Append the ‘&’ character to the output string.
3. Percent encode the URL and append it to the output string.
4. Append the ‘&’ character to the output string.
5. Percent encode the parameter string and append it to the output
   string.

(Extracted from: [creating signatures](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures))

Now you have something like this encoded base url:

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Ffriends%2Flist.json%3Fcursor%3D-1%26skip_status%3Dtrue%26include_user_entities%3Dfalse&oauth_consumer_key%3Dremoved%26oauth_nonce%3D1423633315%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1423633315%26oauth_token%3Dremoved%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

And maybe you must try to get this:

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Ffriends%2Flist.json&cursor%3D-1%26skip_status%3Dtrue%26include_user_entities%3Dfalse%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dremoved%26oauth_nonce%3D1423633315%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1423633315%26oauth_token%3Dremoved%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using `rawurlencode` on the `=` symbol.  That will convert it to `%3D`.

So you're getting `cursor%3D-1` when you want `cursor=-1`.

Perhaps try simplifying the function so that you don't encode the `=`?

Answer (score -2):

This is the sample code for getting user Information

```
       require_once('oauth/twitteroauth.php'); 

$oauth_token='YOUR OAUTH TOKEN';
$oauth_token_secret='YOUR SECRET KEY';
function getConnectionWithAccessToken($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);

$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```